# Python - SkLearn Logistic Regression: One-by-one train instance

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

Here is my question, I have a huge train set so I can't load it in memory and apply this code.

```py
model = LogisticRegression()
model = model.fit(train_set_df, y_label_df)
```

So, I am looking for a way to train my Sklearn.LogisticRegression model by passing instances one-by-one in order to avoid loading all the train data in memory. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the `partial_fit` method. `LogisticRegression` does not support it. You can use `MultinomialNB` (or any other Naive Bayes) or `SGDClassifier` instead.